# Where to park a car in Helsinki?

Tags: automobiles, helsinki

I am planning to visit Helsinki by car and also to make a short visit to Sweden on boat. I am worried about where to leave a car while being away from the city.

What are safe and not much expensive options for parking the car in Helsinki for a couple of days?

Answer (score 2):

The easy & convenient option is to park directly at the ferry terminal:

http://www.portofhelsinki.fi/en/passengers/parking-terminals

There are a number of these, so you'll need to check which one your ferry company uses, and prices will vary based on location and length of stay, but as an example, two days parking at the central Hansa Terminal will cost you around 30 EUR.

Comment: Mind though that Vuosaari harbour is not exactly near Helsinki.

Comment: @RHA Scroll down: there is public parking at each of Helsinki's harbours.

Comment: I knew already, but many people would be surprised to find out how far it is.